# Android WebView - call POST method with header

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I want to call `POST` method on WebView with header. I am using:

```kotlin
webView.postUrl("url", byteArrayOf())
```

My `webView` has assigned `webViewClient` that has overridden `shouldInterceptRequest`:

```kotlin
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
    view: WebView?,
    request: WebResourceRequest?
): WebResourceResponse? {
    return if (request?.url?.toString()?.equals("url") == true) {
        try {
            val connection: HttpURLConnection = 
                URL(request.url.toString()).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.setRequestProperty("Header-Name", "Value")
            connection.connect() // Error is thrown here
            val inputStream: InputStream = connection.inputStream
            WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", inputStream)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
    } else {
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
    }
}
```

But it isn't working I am getting the following errors:

1. I am using [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/). This error occurs when SSL Proxying is **disabled**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

2. This error occurs when SSL Proxying is **enabled**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: C=NZ, ST=Auckland, L=Auckland, O=XK72 Ltd, OU=https://charlesproxy.com/ssl, CN="Charles Proxy CA (5 Aug 2021, LAPTOP)
```

I also tried to add this header directly from Charles not from code (so in this case I am calling `postUrl` but `shouldInterceptRequest` is commented/not used). And this is working.

Why does this happen? Is something wrong with `shouldInterceptRequest`? Or maybe is there any other simpler way to call a POST method in a WebView with a header?